# Question about Bayesian Inference, Posterior Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, bayesian

I have a posterior probability of $p_i$ which is based on a Beta prior and some data from a binomial distribution:

I have another procedure:

$$P(E)=\prod_{i \in I} p_i^{k_i}(1-p_i)^{1-k_i}$$

which gives me the probability of a specific event of successes and failures for the set of $I$ in a model. Given the posterior distribution for $p_i$, how do I find $P(E)$?

UPDATE: I think the issue may be the notation. $P(E)$ should actually be $P(E|p_1,\dotsc,p_i,\dotsc,p_{|I|})$. Then if we are looking for the marginal probability, $P(E)$, then we need to solve for 
$$\int \dotsi \int_{0}^{1} P(E|p_1,\dotsc,p_i,\dotsc,p_{|I|})P(p_1,,\dotsc,p_i,\dotsc,p_{|I|})\, dp_i.$$ 
Because the $p_i$'s are all independent, we can probably simplify the question a lot.

Comment: Is the idea that you're interested in the joint distribution of some subset of the Bernoulli random variables within the Binomial distribution? Not really sure what you're trying to ask here.